# How can I install SpacyTextBlob on Google Colab Notebooks? AttributeError: has no attribute "factory"

Tags: google-colaboratory, attributeerror

I am trying to use SpacyTextBlob to perform sentiment analysis on a series of articles.
Therefore I use Google Colab.

Colab throws the following error, when following the instructions from the spacytextblob website. *AttributeError: type object "language" has no attribute "factory"*

What can I do?

```
import spacy
!pip install spacytextblob
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe("spacytextblob")
doc = nlp(text)
```

Also, when I try to install the required data to get started, I get a SyntaxError

```
python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Answer (score 0):

After you run

```
!pip install spacytextblob
```

If you look closely at the output, you are told that you need to restart the runtime. I failed to do this on my first try, and got the same error message you are getting. After I restarted the runtime (Menu bar > Runtime > Restart Runtime), spacytexblob ran without issues.